# CPU instruction set

Tags: data-request, computing

I would like to have a structured dataset about [instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) by CPU. The data should include the number of cycles, ALU, FPU used, etc.

Does this exist somewhere?

Comment: I'm interested too. When you say CPU, you mean x86 compatible CPU (intel and amd) or you want something more, like arm cpus?

Comment: I am open to any kind of data

Comment: Wikidata is starting to have CPU support. Have a look at https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Property:P1068 and 
http://tools.wmflabs.org/autolist/autolist1.html?q=claim%5B31%3A272683%5D

Comment: You mean something like http://pds.twi.tudelft.nl/vakken/in101/labcourse/instruction-set/ http://pds.twi.tudelft.nl/vakken/in101/labcourse/instruction-set/lmw.html for multiple architectures?

Answer (score 1):

Only a single architecture, but maybe helpful nevertheless:

The educational **[MMIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX) architecture** by Donald Knuth has a [full list of instructions](http://mmix.cs.hm.edu/doc/instructions-en.html) on their current website, including opcodes, signature and timing information (e.g. ADDU = 1 cycle, MULU = 10 cycles).

However, the list of instructions is not available as a machine-readable format, but might be parsable with a bit of RegExp matching of HTML lists and tables. This compact [table of all opcodes](http://mmix.cs.hm.edu/doc/opcodes.html) might facilitate that task.